# Searching for syntax errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

For class we were given a source code that was riddled with syntax errors. I fixed some of the more obvious syntax issues. Here is the code so far:

```
def findNumInList():
    for i in (myList):
        if(myList[i] == num):
            print("Found number %s" %num)

def main():
    myList = [1,25,7,99,12]

    #Gets number from user, and appends it to the existing list
    num = int(input("Enter a number to be added to the end of the list: "))
    myList.append(num)

    #Checks to see if number was successfully added to the list
    findNumInList()
main()
```

What I am still getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "part1.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
  File "part1.py", line 15, in main
    findNumInList()
  File "part1.py", line 3, in findNumInList
    for i in (myList):
NameError: global name 'myList' is not defined
```

How is myList not defined?

Answer (score 1):

`main()` is called first, and the list is defined there, however it only exists in the scope of that function, so the `findNumInList` function doesn't know it.

A solution would be to pass the list to the function:

```
def findNumInList(myList, num):
    for i in (myList):
        if(myList[i] == num):
            print("Found number %s" %num)

def main():
    myList = [1,25,7,99,12]

    #Gets number from user, and appends it to the existing list
    num = int(input("Enter a number to be added to the end of the list: "))
    myList.append(num)

    #Checks to see if number was successfully added to the list
    findNumInList(myList, num)
main()
```

Edit: same goes for the `num` variable

Comment: I have done that. When that runs it then says num is not defined.

Comment: list index out of range??

Comment: `if(myList[i] == num)` should really be `if(i == num)`, but that is another issue

Comment: @JoeBob This is not a helpdesk service. The purpose of this site is to answer one, precisely defined question at time. If you have another question, post it as such. But I'd advise first to try on your own - these are very trivial problems, covered in any Python tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Consider reading about what a [*scope*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) is in Python:

> [...]Usually, the local scope references the local names of the (textually) current function. Outside functions, the local scope references the same namespace as the global scope: the module’s namespace. [...]

Your variable is in the scope of the `main` function, which is a *local scope*. You can't access variables between local scopes. As [Tim Castelijns showed in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26620338/2642204), a possible solution is to pass the list as an argument.